# Code completion is not working when using symfony container services

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, fosuserbundle, autosuggest, code-completion

I'm using FOSUserBundle in my Symfony 2 application and was wondering how to make a code completion work  in PHPStorm, because when you inject the service via container like:

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
```

And trying to use $userManager to see its interface - I see nothing, because for PHPStorm this is a regular variable, not an object built via "new" operator.

Is there a way to make it show me the available methods for this object?

Like we usually do with real objects:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign to the variable an annotation like showed below to tell to phpstorm from which class the variable receive the instance (ps: I don't use fosUserBundle).

```
/** @var \myProject\appBundle\entityManager $userManager */
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
```

PS: Have you installed the [Symfony2 plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm)?

Comment: Everything worked. I didn't know about variable's annotations until now :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, executing

```
composer update
```

in the console worked.